# Formula to generate sequence while enforcing a particular number within X items

Tags: probability

I need to generate a sequence of 0s and 1s. I want to ensure that there's always at least one 1 within a sequence of 8 numbers. What formula do I use to generate this sequence?
One option would be enforce a 1 on every 8th number and then use different probabilities for the remaining 7 items. However, I would prefer avoiding a sequence as predictable as this.

Comment: We need more criteria to specify a unique solution: exactly how would you like the numbers to be distributed?  For instance, you could require that in the long run there be equal numbers of zeros and ones and you could also require that in some sense the values be as independent of each other as possible (recognizing that your condition imposes a mild form of dependence).  Good answers, btw, will describe the probability distributions they are generating: that's crucial information to know.

Comment: Note that the most general solution (where "sequence of 8 numbers" is interpreted as *any* window of length 8) for sequences beginning with a 1 is a random variable $(X,Y)$ where $X$ has positive integral values and $Y$ has integral values between 1 and 7.  Interpret $(X,Y)$ as a sequence of $X$ ones followed by a sequence of $Y$ zeros.  Repeat using another such random variable (possibly with a different distribution and possibly dependent on the first) and continue in this wise as long as needed.  A similar solution holds for sequences beginning with a 0.

Answer (score 1):

Generate your first seven entries by tossing a coin with the appropriate probability.

Starting with the eighth entry, always look back to the seven previous entries before generating a new one. If there are no 1s in the last seven entries, the new one *must* be a 1. If there *is* a 1, again simply determine the new entry by tossing your coin.

Overall, you will get slightly more 1s than just tossing each coin independently with the input probability would yield, but that is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Or, just generate integers in the range 1..255, and represent them in binary.

Comment: This is clever but it doesn't work when "at least one 1 within a sequence of 8 numbers" is interpreted in a moving window sense rather than a block sense.  For instance, the pair of numbers (128, 1) in binary is 10000000 00000001, containing many windows of size 8 that lack a 1. One way to overcome the problem is to generate integers in 1..15 instead.